# Embed a library into executable

Tags: cocoa, compiler-construction, linker

I thought that importing `.a` library (instead of `.dylib`) into Xcode 5 project will automatically embed the library code into an executable:

[image: Link Binary With Libraries]

But it still creates a small (57 kB) exe, obviously without boost & libtorrent.

`otool -L` gives:

```
/usr/local/lib/libtorrent-rasterbar.7.dylib (compatibility version 8.0.0, current version 8.0.0)
libboost_system.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
libboost_filesystem.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
/usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 120.0.0)
/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1197.1.1)
```

Why `.dylib`? Why it still needs dynamic libraries?

Of course that executable cannot run on a Mac without these libraries:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: libboost_system.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/d/Test1
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

Comment: Have you added those line to a copy phase when building?

Comment: What and where to copy? (I want to embed a library into exe, as a usual static library.)

Comment: Check out copy files build phase and copy the libraries to the app when building . Then they are available only.

Comment: Copy to the... "app"? Cannot see this option: http://i.stack.imgur.com/YpSgZ.png